# Create a command line from a list of arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, console

In Python I know packages like `click` or `argparse` to implement command line interfaces.
However, I'm in search for something the other way round. Something like a commandline assembler.
I need to set-up some complex command strings in python before executing them using `subprocess`.

Currently, for every command line tool I need to execute there exists code like the following and I would like to improve on that:

```
TOOLPATH = "x/y/z/tool.exe"


def setup_command_line(par: dict):
    cmd = ["stdbuf", "-oP", TOOLPATH, "-I", "2", "-flast"]
    cmd += ["-T", "1024"]
    cmd += ["-p", str(par["port"])]

    if "direction" in par:
        cmd.append("-r")
        if par["l4"]["type"] == "udp":
            cmd.append("-F")
    else:
        cmd.append("-x")

    [...]

    cmd += [par["proto"]["myproto"]]
    return cmd
```

This kind of low level code which concatenates some strings/lists is not really generic, a little cumbersome to get it right as well as tends to produce messy code. I would like to have something more high level, reusable and generic.
I would like to encapsulate the low level operations.

Additionally it should be possible to tell if the windows-style '/' or the linux style '-' should be used to introduce an option. Some args need to be quoted using either `"` or `'`, ... .

So the flow would be sth like this:

1. specify the style (windows or linux)
2. specify some filename for an executable which should be executed
3. specify the command line args, options and flags appended to the filename
4. generate the complete command line as a string (for diagnose output) as well as a list (for subprocess)
5. execute the command

So I started defining my own classes, which currently implement only a rudimentary set of the functionality I would like to obtain (e.g. the optional argument quoting is not implemented). However, I think you get the idea:

**Baseclass**

```
import typing
import subprocess


class ShellParam:
    def __init__(self, ident: str, arg: typing.Optional[typing.Union[str, int, float]],
                 prefix: str):
        self._ident = ident.strip()
        self._arg = str(arg).strip()
        self._prefix = prefix.strip()

    def __str__(self):
        tmp_str = self._prefix + self._ident
        if tmp_str != "":
            tmp_str += " "
        tmp_str += str(self._arg)
        return tmp_str.rstrip()
```

**Derived classes**

```
class ShellOption(ShellParam):
    # A shell option normally consists of a prefix (e.g. the '-' character on linux or the '/' character on windows)
    # and an identifier to distinguish it from other options as well as the value which may be specified behind an option
    # Options without args are called flags (see below)
    def __init__(self, ident: str, value: typing.Optional[typing.Union[str, int, float]] = "", prefix: str = "-"):
        super().__init__(ident, value, prefix)


class ShellArg(ShellParam):
    # Specifies a (positional) shell argument which has no corresponding prefix, e.g. a filename.
    # Therefore, the identifier is omitted, too
    # Only the value is important
    def __init__(self, value: typing.Optional[typing.Union[str, int, float]] = ""):
        super().__init__("", value, "")


class ShellFlag(ShellParam):
    # Specifies flags which can be present or not. If they are present they are set (True) otherwise not (False)
    def __init__(self, ident: str, prefix: str = "-"):
        super().__init__(ident, "", prefix)
```

**Factory**

```
class ParamFactory:
    def __init__(self, default_prefix = "-"):
        self._default_prefix = default_prefix

    def make_option(self, ident: str, value: typing.Optional[typing.Union[str, int, float]] = "", prefix: str = ""):
        return ShellOption(ident, value, prefix or self._default_prefix)

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    # -> disabled for consistency to other factory methods
    def make_arg(self, value: typing.Union[str, int, float]):
        return ShellArg(value)

    def make_flag(self, ident: str, prefix: str = ""):
        return ShellFlag(ident, prefix or self._default_prefix)

    def make_param(self, ident: str, value: typing.Optional[typing.Union[str, int, float]], prefix: str):
        if ident == "" and prefix == "":
            return self.make_arg(value)
        elif value == "":
            return self.make_flag(ident, prefix)
        else:
            return self.make_option(ident, value, prefix)
```

**Assembler**

```
# The _ShellFlagBaseType cannot be passed to the Union in order to avoid repetition
# However, it is needed for type assertions and therefore maintained separately
_ShellParamBaseType = (ShellParam, str, )
_ShellParamUnionType = typing.Union[ShellParam, str, ]
ShellParamsType = typing.Union[_ShellParamUnionType, list[_ShellParamUnionType], ]


class CmdAss:
    def __init__(self, cmd: str, default_prefix = "-"):
        self._cmd: str = cmd
        self._args: ShellParamsType = list()
        self._param_factory = ParamFactory(default_prefix)

    def add_params(self, params: ShellParamsType):
        if not isinstance(params, typing.Iterable):
            params = [params]

        for param in params:
            self.add_param(param)

    def add_param(self, param: _ShellParamUnionType,
                  arg: typing.Optional[typing.Union[str, int, float]] = "",
                  prefix: str = ""):
        try:
            if not isinstance(param, ShellParam):
                if isinstance(param, str):
                    param = self._param_factory.make_param(param, arg, prefix)
                else:
                    raise CMDAssError(f"Invalid shell parameter: {param}")

            self._args.append(param)
        except TypeError as ex:
            raise CMDAssError("Cannot append param. Wrong type!") from ex

    def run(self) -> typing.Union[subprocess.CompletedProcess, subprocess.CompletedProcess[str]]:
        try:
            decoded_cmdline = list(map(str, self.cmd_with_args))
        except TypeError:
            raise CMDAssError("Could not decode command line: '{self._cmdline}'")

        sp = subprocess
        output = sp.run(decoded_cmdline, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT, encoding="utf-8")
        return output

    @property
    def cmd_with_args(self) -> ShellParamsType:
        return [self._cmd] + self._args

    def __str__(self):
        return " ".join(map(str, self.cmd_with_args))
```

Currently, as I just started I didn't put so much effort into the task. Now, when I continue the project it is a reasonable question if I should implement everything by myself or if I could improve my code by basing it on something which already exists.
E.g. the click parser has some functionality I maybe could use. However, it is not intended as a command line assembler but more as a command line parser. Although there probably exists some common functionality between parser and assembler.

The point is, that I need something reusable. I have several command line tools to deal with and I don't want to repeatedly implement all the string and/or list concatenation for every tool I need to control.
This really gets too messy and contradicts DRY paradigm.

**Example code**

```
ass = CmdAss("command")
ass.add_param("a", "b", "/")
print(str(ass))

new_param = ShellOption("x", 123, "/")
ass.add_param(new_param)
print(str(ass))
```

**->**

```
command /a b
command /a b /x 123
```

Comment: You could make the default prefix os-dependent (`/` on nt, `-` on posix). But I actually think, that this whole thing is a classical case of over-engineering.

Comment: I think it depends on the complexity of the command to be executed. To execute `ls -la dir  | grep something` it would probably be over-engineering. As shown in the `setup_command_line` some preparation would need many if-thens, some preparation would need complex quoting, some preparation would need complex options with many different parameters. Having a set of base-classes I could implement such special cases in a derived class and still use the common functionality. Using a low-level approach I would need to implement everything by scratch again and again.

Comment: `"stdbuf", "-oP", TOOLPATH, "-I", "2", "-flast"` is deeply suspicious. What is the reason for wanting to change pipe buffering behaviour when you're using `subprocess` and not a shell?